# Excel: Cell with multiple lines of text into one line of text

Tags: vba, excel

I have about 4000 cells, each with about 4 separate lines of text. Each line of texts has been entered using the ALT+ENTER method.

Can anybody suggest a way, either VBA or Excel command/method to convert each of of these cells into one line, with spaces between the words.

Example:
Current
Cell 1:

- About
- Horse
- Dog

Need:
Cell 1:

- About Horse Dog

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    rng.Replace what:=Chr(10), lookat:=xlPart, replacement:=" "
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12):

**To do this without VBA:**

Use find and replace.

In the find what box, hold ALT and type `0010`
(ASCII code for line feed is 10 - you will not see anything, but it's a new line character).

In the replace box, simply type a space character or any delimiter.

Click on `Replace all` buttton.

Answer (score 6):

ALT+ENTER creates a character called vbLF (for visual basic Line Feed). You simply want to replace the vbLF with a space, like so:

```
Sub test()
    Dim str As String
    str = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print str
    str = Replace(str, vbLf, " ")
    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

To place it in a loop:

```
Sub test()
    dim i as integer
    Dim str As String

    for i = 1 to 10 '(however many you want, can also be dynamic - use XlUp if you want to)
       str = Range("A" & i)
       Debug.Print str
       str = Replace(str, vbLf, " ")
       Debug.Print str
    next
End Sub
```

Comment: This would only fix cell A1.  To use function `Replace` to fix all cells, you would need to loop over all cells.

Comment: Well... yes. Simply need to place it in a for loop. I can add it if you think it's necessary.

Comment: Have you timed this code looping over 4000 cells?  As a one-off exercise this may be adequate but I do not think this is a good approach.

Comment: I concede find and replace will be faster - possibly under 1 second. My method will probably take a few seconds. Nothing dramatic on its own but if it is part of a larger code Find and Replace is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

I think this will do what you want:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Cells.Replace What:=vbLf, Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

A little search on your favorite browser:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/03/remove-carriage-returns-excel/

if it's a "one shot" no need to create a VBA macro. Replace carriage returns by a space, and the job should be done